# redirecting to index.html when no action specified in MVC4

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, routes

I am building a website, in which I want to have a static html to be served when root of the application is accessed and when an action is specified, it need to redirect to appropriate controller.

For instance, www.abc.com has index.html at its root folder, the index.html has to be served when user types www.abc.com, which will have links to other pages like www.abc.com/home/index

I am hosting this in windows azure websites, so IIS configuration may not be possible. Is there any other way to ignore particular scenario using route table or other means?

Answer (score 0):

Create separate Action and its view. The same action will be your default root.

```
public ActionResult StartIndex()    
{
    return View();
}
```

inside view StartIndex.cshtml you can write script as shown below

```
@{ Layout=null; }
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      window.location.href='www.abc.com';
  });
</script>
```

It may helps you.

Comment: I just wanted to avoid the redirection because the home page will have more hits

Answer (score 0):

I got this solved by removing the default controller in routes table.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Now unless a controller is specified, it is launching the index.html